# How to scroll to previous location on macOS?

Tags: mouse, ui, macos

When I grab the slider with the mouse pointer and start scrolling I can't go back to the exact location of where I started. I tried pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> before releasing the mouse button but that doesn't work. I also tried the Windows way: drag the pointer to the left. You could guess.

Are there any OS-wide keyboard combinations to *undo* scrolling?

My *example* use case: I am reading some long text in a word processor and I just want to check something that is 50 pages away then go back.

The OS version is Sonoma but I was missing this feature from Lion too.

Comment: Which word processor? Pages? MS Word? Different apps may have different methods. Also, what model Mac and OS version? Incidentally, you shouldn't need to drag the scroll bar often. Either scroll with the mouse (if it has a scroll wheel), or use the Page Up/Down keys. Also: on Windows, you're saying that dragging the pointer "to the left" (where?) takes you to the page you were previously looking at? or Editing...?

Comment: My use case is just an example, there are different applications with long documents. I am looking for an OS-wide solution. The scroll wheel or Page keys are not a solution to my problem. MacOS version doesn't matter as this didn't work in Lion, Mavericks... nor in Sonoma.
On Windows if you drag the pointer – without releasing the mouse button – some (100? 200?) pixel away from the scrollbar the scroll jumps back to where it was before scrolling. If you drag the pointer back to the scrollbar it will show temporarily the exact location.

Answer (score 1):

If I leave the cursor in Word for example where I was last editing, then, when I scroll and want to go back I just type a space and the view is back to where I left the cursor.

However, if you scroll and click in the new location that no longer works.

Another "trick" I use is to enter special words (words that are not used at all in the doc...) at certain locations so I can just do a "find" - worked very well on my final year project as thoughts of edits in odd places came to mind.

Comment: I use this trick as a workaround where editing is possible. But what about read only documents or PDFs without TOC?